# Semantic way to have navigation inside a table?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have what is essentially tabular data - a list of products. Currently, I have this marked up as a `table`, with a `thead` on top which contains a description of the column and `tbody` which contains the actual content.

Now, the problem is that when you click on a product, it expands and a row appears underneath with various links such as "rename", "delete" and so on.

Is there a semantically sound way of doing that? It doesn't make sense to me to put anything but th and `td` inside of `tr`s (and it's probably not even allowed as per the spec) and adding a separate row for the menu is not optimal either.

Answer (score 1):

> I have what is essentially tabular data - a list of products

Semantically, a list of products is a list.

Use a ul or ol instead of a table.

Comment: In that case, how would I do the header? Above the list of products I currently have a `thead` which contains `th`s with name, price and so on, [like this](http://pastebin.com/1miZgZL4)

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing now.  You can put an "actions" div or similar in the td.  That's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a semantic approach, don't use tables in this situation.